# New input after giving a wrong input

Tags: python, arrays

```
a = input()   
def word_to_list(a):
        b = str(a)
        code2 = []
        for digit in b:
            code2.append (int(digit))
        if len(code2) != 4:
            print("no right amount")
        else:
            print(code2)
code2 = word_to_list(a)
```

I got this code and what I want is that you can do another try when the code is to short, (because you need a length of 4). Does somebody know how that works, so that you can do a new input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call the function from within itself after getting the new input, like this:

```
def word_to_list(a):
    code = []
    for digit in str(a):
        code.append(int(digit))
    if len(code) != 4:
        print("no right amount")
        # Input a new value, then call function with it again
        word_to_list(input())
    else:
        print(code)

code2 = word_to_list(input())
```

This (recursive call) acts as a loop, in the sense that it'll keep asking the use for a code until he inputs a code of length 4.

Here's a shorter, more efficient equivalent version:

```
def code_to_list(c):
    code_to_list(input("Try again")) if len(c) != 4 else print([int(d) for d in c])
```

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet uses a `while` loop to do what you want. It does check for being less than 4 rather than being not equal to 4, since I wasn't exactly sure what you wanted. It first asks for a code word, and it keeps asking till the user inputs one that is long enough. I shortened `word_to_list()` by using a list comprehension.

```
code2 = input()
while len(code2) < 4:
    code2 = input()
code2 = [int(c) for c in code2]
```